# Jenkinsfile not detecting the aws plugin syntaxes

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-pipeline

I've installed below Plugins on Jenkins 2.249.3 version

1. https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws/
2. https://plugins.jenkins.io/aws-codepipeline/
3. https://plugins.jenkins.io/aws-credentials/

My JenkinsFile is as below

```
pipeline {
  agent {
        node {
            label 'docker-01'
        }
  }
  stages {
    stage("Build Artefacts") {
      steps {
        sh 'echo \'Hello world!\' > out.txt'
      }
    }
    stage("Upload to AWS") {
      steps {
        sh 'echo \'Hello world Again!\''
        withAWS(region:'us-east-1',credentials:'SwapnilAWS') {
          s3Upload(file:'out.txt', bucket:'mybucket', path:'out.txt')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I even used `#!/usr/bin/env groovy` at the beginning of `JenkinsFile` but it didn't helped me here

But, I'm getting errors as, Not sure what I'm missing here?

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 18: Invalid parameter "file", did you mean "entries"? @ line 18, column 20.
             s3Upload(file:'out.txt', bucket:'mybucket', path:'out.txt')
                      ^

WorkflowScript: 18: Invalid parameter "bucket", did you mean "entries"? @ line 18, column 36.
             s3Upload(file:'out.txt', bucket:'mybucket', path:'out.txt')
                                      ^

WorkflowScript: 18: Invalid parameter "path", did you mean "entries"? @ line 18, column 69.
   ket:'mybucket', path:'out.
                                 ^

3 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:337)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Are you using the newest version of the AWS plugin?

Comment: Found a very similar github issue: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin/issues/227

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKemmerzell yes without restarting AWS Pipeline plugin get installed but those DSLs will be available only after full Jenkins restart. Thank you 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found a very similar github issue:
> github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin/issues/227 – Michael
> Kemmerzell 23 hours ago

Thanks to @MichaelKemmerzell yes without restarting AWS Pipeline plugin get installed but those DSLs will be available only after full Jenkins restart.